# Custom style of expander button of an ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I would like to replace the default button style of a grouping header in an ExpandableListView (placed as gray button with black arrow on the left side of a group) by an own style.

Has anyone an idea or a reference to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`ExpandableListView#setGroupIndicator(Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method.